# how to get radio button in each items recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I was a little confused in this case, I saw different examples, but I did not see what I think is complete. If you have a better example for me in this case, thank you for helping me in this case so that I can solve this issue much better. To.
Thanks